# Server Side Test A/B + GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, ab-testing

I just created my server side A/B test following this https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/experiments;

But i dont have GA tracker in my code anymore since we are using Google Tag Manager.

How to replace this ga('set', 'exp', '$experimentId.$variationId'); using GTM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In GA -> Variable (GA Settings) or into your PageView Tag you can add expId and ExpVariant. Really hard to find a solution for this but it makes sense now.

[image]